# Would it be possible to create a class during runtime execution?

Tags: java

This might  be a little unrealistic bu i will ask anyway.
Would this be possible to create literally create a new class during the run time execution, i don't mean a new instance, i mean a new class created from the code itself.

I'm actually using reflection in java, i can get the field's name of the class and the method, i find this powerful.

So i was asking to myself if this would be possible to make that create a new class during the run time execution.

Comment: Keep in mind that using reflection when you don't need reflection introduces more problems than it solve. Save Reflection for problems that _need_ reflection!

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: @gnat that's why i used "Woulds it be poosible"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is not k only possible but actually quite common. You can create your own byte code and feed it to a ClassLoader instance to turn it into a Class object and then use reflection to create and manipulate it. There's a library called cglib that's commonly used to make it easier, and many frameworks and libraries (eg Spring and Hibernate) use this approach to implement some of their features.

Comment: when you say "you can create your own byte code", what does it mean concretely ? In term of code, could you provide a little exemple or give me more information ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible, but *why* do you feel the need to?

Reflection has its uses, to be sure, but with Great Power comes Great ... Opportunities to Shoot Yourself in the Foot in New and Exciting Ways (and just when you least expected it, too).

That aren't that many things that actually *need* Reflection, so I would suggest that if you find yourself reaching into the toolbox for that particular spanner on a *regular* basis, you really should be asking yourself "why?".

If nothing else, Reflection allows you to break through the "interface" of other people's code, which is *lovely*; right up to the point that they *change* the internal implementation of their class (which they're perfectly within their rights to do).  Anyone who programmed to their published Interface is fine; their code will continue to work.  Your Reflection-based code, which is now looking for things that no longer exist, will crash and burn.

Comment: haha i know i should not make this useless comment but i laughed at "but with Great Power comes Great ... Opportunities to Shoot Yourself in the Foot in New and Exciting Ways", very funny